# How to add new table to sqlite?

Tags: dart, flutter, sqflite

I need to add a new column name `id INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT` and a new table for the current database for my existing table. How to use 'onUpgrade'? Is it need to change the version number?

```
initDb() async {
    io.Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, "HelperDatabase.db");
    var theDb = await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _onCreate, onUpgrade: _onUpgrade);
    return theDb;
  }
```

**How to use `_onUpgrade`**

```
void _onUpgrade(Database db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)async{

  }
```

**Is it need to add column also?**

```
void _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {

    await db.execute(
        """CREATE TABLE AssetAssemblyTable(e INTEGER, a INTEGER, c INTEGER)""");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To update your DB from old version, you should change `version` to `2`.
You should change `onCreate` and `onUpdate` like below.

```
// This is called for new users who have no old db
void _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {

  // if `AssetAssemblyTable` has a new column in version 2, add the column here.
  await db.execute(
    """CREATE TABLE AssetAssemblyTable(e INTEGER, a INTEGER, c INTEGER)""");
  )
  await db.execute("CREATE TABLE NewTable...") // create new Table
}

// This is called for existing users who have old db(version 1) 
void _onUpgrade(Database db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)async{
  // In this case, oldVersion is 1, newVersion is 2
  if (oldVersion == 1) {
      await db.execute("ALTER TABLE AssetAssemblyTable...") // add new column to existing table.
      await db.execute("CREATE TABLE NewTable...") // create new Table
  }
}
```

more example is below

https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite/doc/migration_example.md

Comment: is it needs to increase `_onCreate()` method version number whenAlter table?

Comment: You don't have to do something with `version` variable in `_onCreate`.  I guess that it is for debugging purpose.

Comment: Errror Message: ```Unhandled Exception: DatabaseException(table UsernameTable has no column named rememberMe (Sqlite code 1): , while compiling: INSERT OR REPLACE  INTO UsernameTable (username, rememberMe) VALUES (?, ?), (OS error - 2:No such file or directory)) sql 'INSERT OR REPLACE  INTO UsernameTable (username, rememberMe) VALUES (?, ?)' args [term@melfs, 1]}```

Comment: ```initDb() async {
    io.Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, "HelperDatabase.db");
    var theDb = await openDatabase(path, version: 4, onCreate: _onCreate, onUpgrade: _onUpgrade);
    return theDb;
  }```

Comment: ```void _onUpgrade(Database db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)async{
    if(oldVersion != 5){
      await db.execute("ALTER TABLE UsernameTable ADD COLUMN rememberMe INTEGER DEFAULT 0");
    }
  }```

Comment: can to answer this question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/56323951/8822337

Answer (score 0):

Here what I've done :

```
class SqliteDB {
   static final SqliteDB _instance = new SqliteDB.internal();

   factory SqliteDB() => _instance;
   static Database? _db;

   Future<Database?> get db async {
     if (_db != null) {
        return _db;
      }
     _db = await initDb();
     return _db;
   }

   SqliteDB.internal();

   /// Initialize DB
   initDb() async {
     io.Directory documentDirectory = await 
     getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
     String path = join(documentDirectory.path, "RadiosStations.db");
     
     var taskDb = await openDatabase(
        //open the database or create a database if there isn't any path,
        version: 2, onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {

        await db.execute(
          """CREATE TABLE AssetAssemblyTable(e INTEGER, a INTEGER, c 
             INTEGER)""");
            )

        await db.execute("CREATE TABLE NewTable...") // create new Table;

        },
      onUpgrade: (Database db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)async{
        // In this case, oldVersion is 1, newVersion is 2
      if (oldVersion == 1) {
        await db.execute(
            """CREATE TABLE AssetAssemblyTable(e INTEGER, a INTEGER, c 
     INTEGER)""");
      )
      await db.execute("CREATE TABLE NewTable...") // create new Table;
      }}
);
return taskDb;}
```