# OnUpgrade SQFLITE: Unhandled Exception: DatabaseException(table UsernameTable has no column named rememberMe (Sqlite code 1):

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, sqflite

> Unhandled Exception: DatabaseException(table UsernameTable has no
>   column named rememberMe (Sqlite code 1): , while compiling: INSERT OR
>   REPLACE  INTO UsernameTable (username, rememberMe) VALUES (?, ?), (OS
>   error - 2:No such file or directory)) sql 'INSERT OR REPLACE  INTO
>   UsernameTable (username, rememberMe) VALUES (?, ?)' args [term@melfs,
>   1]}

I upgraded my DB. I added new column to `UsernameTable` Table. But It's not working. I have already so many records in this db. I can't `drop` So How I do add new column to exisiting db. I used `Sqflite`

```
 initDb() async {
    io.Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, "HelperDatabase.db");
    var theDb = await openDatabase(path, version: 4, onCreate: _onCreate, onUpgrade: _onUpgrade);
    return theDb;
  }
```

**OnUpgrade method.**

```
 void _onUpgrade(Database db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)async{
  if(oldVersion != 5){
      await db.execute("ALTER TABLE UsernameTable ADD COLUMN rememberMe INTEGER DEFAULT 0");
    }
  }
```

**onCreate method**

```
  void _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
 await db.execute("""CREATE TABLE UsernameTable(username STRING)""");
}
```

Comment: What value did you get in `oldVersion` and `newVersion` (`_onUpgrade`). I guess query in `onUpgrade` is not being called.

Comment: how to called onUpgrade?

Comment: I added in `initDB()`..

Comment: Try change `version` in `openDatabase()` to `5` or higher. Your DB seems to get wrong condition.

Comment: I did in my code. Isn't it?

Comment: @pompopo you are right. I added `print()` statement to _`onUpgrade()` method. It's not printing

Comment: That's maybe your DB has a higher version than the version specified in `openDatabase`. In this case, `onUpgrade` will not be called. You can debug your db explained in this doc. https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite/doc/dev_tips.md

Comment: @BloodLoss, have you resolved this issue? Could you share some insights on the workaround you've tried?

Comment: @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0 yes I resolved it

Comment: @BloodLoss could you present in the answer section the solution you've used to resolve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that the db version matches to be able to access the database. Verify if the `_onUpgrade()` method - where a new version seems to be passed is being called. Automatic version management during open on sqflite is also available if that's something that you consider.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy to understand `onUpgrade` method I wrote:

```
Future<void> _onUpgrade(Database db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) async {
    for (var version = oldVersion + 1; version <= newVersion; version++) {
        switch (version) {
            case 1: {
                //Version 1 - no changes (won't enter here)
                break;
            }
            case 2: {
                await db.execute('ALTER TABLE xxx ADD COLUMN yyy INTEGER DEFAULT 0');
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If your database is currently on `version 3`, and you update to `version 5` this will enter in case `version 4` and `version 5`

So each time you do changes to the database and increment the version, just add the changes in the switch for that new version, keeping all the previous version changes in tact.